# Bigquery Scripting IF with two conditions ( IF AND IF )

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to be able to apply two conditions on my IF before the Then kick in, but I am not able to find out the syntax.

Example that I want to achieve
Logic:

```
IF condition1 and IF condition 2 THEN execute
```

Query:

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(1) AS cnt
FROM table.__TABLES_SUMMARY__
WHERE table_id = 'test_table_1'   ) = 0 
AND IF (SELECT COUNT(1) AS cnt
FROM table.__TABLES_SUMMARY__
WHERE table_id = 'test_table_2'   ) > 0 
THEN
select 'blabla';
END IF
```

Not sure there is a way to achieve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below should do it

```
IF (
  SELECT COUNT(1) AS cnt
  FROM `your_project.your_dataset`.__TABLES_SUMMARY__
  WHERE table_id = 'test_table_1'   
  ) = 0 
AND (
  SELECT COUNT(1) AS cnt
  FROM `your_project.your_dataset`.__TABLES_SUMMARY__
  WHERE table_id = 'test_table_2'   
  ) > 0 
THEN
  SELECT 'blabla';
ELSE 
  SELECT 'Oops!';
END IF;
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way is through nested If Else conditions:-

```
IF (
  SELECT COUNT(1) AS cnt
  FROM `proj.dataset`.__TABLES_SUMMARY__
  WHERE table_id = 'YOUR_NEW_TABLE1'   
  ) = 5 
then
IF (
  SELECT COUNT(1) AS cnt
  FROM `proj.dataset`.__TABLES_SUMMARY__
  WHERE table_id = 'YOUR_NEW_TABLE2'   
  ) > 0 
THEN
  SELECT 'blabla';
ELSE 
  SELECT 'Ohh!';
END IF;
ELSE 
  SELECT 'Ohh!';
END IF;
```